# How can the data of a Corda node be deleted without restarting the node?

Tags: corda

When running Corda nodes for testing or demo purposes, I often find a need to delete all the node's data and start it again.

I know I can do this by:

- Shutting down the node process
- Deleting the node's `persistence.mv.db` file and `artemis` folder
- Starting the node again

However, I would like to know if it is possible to delete the node's data without restarting the node, as this would be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to delete the node's data without restarting the node.

If you are "resetting" the nodes for testing purposes, you should make sure that you are using the Corda testing APIs to allow your contracts and flows to be tested without actually starting a node. See the testing API docs here: https://docs.corda.net/api-testing.html.

One alternative to restarting the nodes would also be to put the demo environment in a VmWare workstation, take a snapshot of the VM while the nodes are still "clean", run the demo, and then reload the snapshot.